# unexpected token '.' when executing a shell command when changing file extension within groovy script

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to run the following command within a .groovy script:

```
sh """#!/bin/bash -ex
    find .. -name "*.gcda" | \
    xargs -I {} sh -c 'file=${0}; echo "${file%.*}".gcno' {} | \
    xargs -I {} sh -c 'gcov {} -o "\$(dirname {})"' \\;
"""
```

Not the prettiest command, but I'm finding a list of `.gcda` file names, changing those strings to have `.gcno` extensions instead, and then finally running a command on the `.gcno` version of the filename.

The error I get:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 92: unexpected token: . @ line 92, column 60.
   h -c 'file=${0}; echo "${file%.*}".gcno'
                                 ^

1 error
```

This command works fine when I run it in the terminal, it just complains when I execute it in Jenkins. I tried escaping a few things but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: why two `sh -c sh -c` ?

Comment: Woops, copying error. Updated the question.

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: unquote `echo ${file%.*}.gcno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem:

```
unexpected token: . @ line 1, column 14.
   """ echo ${1%.} """
                ^
```

This happens because `${..}` in Groovy double quoted strings are used for string interpolation. You instead want Groovy to leave them alone so that the shell can interpret them.

You can do this with triple single quoted, since Groovy does not do string interpolation in those (but unlike bash itself, it still interprets backslashes):

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash -ex
    find .. -name "*.gcda" | \
    xargs -I {} sh -c 'file=${0}; echo "${file%.*}".gcno' {} | \
    xargs -I {} sh -c 'gcov {} -o "$(dirname {})"' \\;
'''
```

Comment: This works, however this does mean giving up the string interpolation. Your answer made me realize that I could simply avoid the interpolation using an extra backslash: `"\${file%.*}".gcno`, just like I did with `dirname` on the next line.

Comment: It looks like you want `find . -name "*.gcda" -exec sh -c 'for file; do f=${file%.*}; gcov "$f" -o "$(dirname "$f")"; done' _ {} +`. Since you used `sh` all the way anyway there is no reason to use `bash` to run just the pipeline (and now there's not even a pipeline) ... but maybe the shebang is ignored here altogether anyway?